# Please how can i draw this vertical chart in Latex?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

How can i draw this diagram in latex?
Any help would be so apreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very simple way to do it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\boxed{\text{difficult problem for an individual operator}} \\
\downarrow \\
\boxed{\text{simpler problem for a \(C^*\)-algebra}} \\
\downarrow \\
\boxed{\text{result for the \(C^*\)-algebra}} \\
\downarrow \\
\boxed{\text{desired result for the individual operator}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

However, if the diagram was more complicated other tools (like TikZ) would be more appropriate.

Comment: nice and fast +1

Comment: Thank you so much, i try it and it works, you saved me.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `Tikz`:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,positioning}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,outer sep=0.5cm]
        

    \node[rectangle,,draw=black](a) at (0,0) {difficult problem for an individual operator};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,below=of a] (b) {simpler problem for a C*-algebra};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,below=of b] (c) {result for the C*-algebra};
    \node[rectangle,draw=black,below=of c] (d) {desired result for the operator};
    
    \draw [->] (a) edge (b) (b) edge (c) (c) edge (d);

    
        \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]